# how-to enable Client-Side validation fora textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc

how-to enable Client-Side validation for a ordinary textbox in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Guthrie just published a [good article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx) on validating models -- and you should think about it as model validation, not textbox validation -- in ASP.NET MVC 2.0.  You might want to check out how they do validation in the NerdDinner example at http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/.

Answer (score 0):

There are various options. If you are using MVC 1 you might want to read this article http://blog.codeville.net/2008/04/30/model-based-client-side-validation-for-aspnet-mvc/. If you are using MVC 2, using DataAnnotations, which has the option of validating on client side.